# Secure Hidden Inputs in Paypal

Tags: mysql, paypal

I'm trying to create a system that accepts payments thru Paypal. I've managed to create one using a sandbox account. The process of the system is that they will select a product (coming from my database), click the "Buy" button of their preferred product, then redirects the user to Paypal. After successfully paying, it will do an Instant Payment Notifications (IPN) that will insert the transaction ID, along with the product ID (hidden input), status, price, currency, etc. into my MySQL database. All goes well.

But my problem is that if a malicious user edits the hidden input fields, they can alter the data of the product that they'll be buying (product ID, price, etc.). So I tried creating a button that [Paypal suggests (encrypted button)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/), which you have to input the products into Paypal along with their corresponding product ID from my database, that if you think of it, is tedious and not a conventional approach. Or did I just misunderstood the tutorial?

Any better approach?

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking the whole solution wrong. The hosted buttons are meant for the cases when you have a few products.

My suggestion, use the passthrough variable "custom", where you on server create a MAC or other keyed hash over product, status, price, currency and user's IP.

This are then embedded in Custom.
On the receiver end, you validate the MAC before treating the payment as valid.

Even if they tamper with the price for example, the resulting MAC would not validate, and you know the payment has been tampered with. Thus you could either do a automatic refund, or you could validate the values harder, for example looking up the price in database and making sure everything match up.

Comment: I was also thinking that the solution will always be at the back-end validation. But whatever course of action of the user, the transaction will still store a record on my account and on his/her Paypal account. I might just add another column on my table that will state the remarks of the user's payments. +1

Comment: What is the problem, if you for example auto refund any invalid transactions? The stored record would not be a problem, especially if you in the refund write something like "Could not find relevant product for hash [MAC here] in database. Payment rejected.". Then its obvious for even a court that you cannot deliver a unknown product and the records in their account mean nothing, since you refunded it.